# What is the Win 10 Event ID for when a crash dump is created?

Tags: windows, crash, debug, dump, events

What is the Win 10 Event ID for when a crash dump (not the BSOD kind) is created?

Comment: What crash dump do you have in mind? Something manually initiated by attaching a debugger?

Comment: no, an auto generated one when explorer.exe crashes for example.

Comment: You shouldn't call these crash *dumps* because nothing gets written to a dump file when an application crashes.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Not by default but you can request the OS to create one: https://helgeklein.com/support/creating-an-application-crash-dump/

Comment: very good. I am referring to the default behavior.

Comment: it creates a .dmp file. those are known as dump files. but it doesn't matter in this context what we call them

Answer (score 1):

Application crashes are event ID 1000 and 1001 for Windows Error Reporting (WER). Hung applications are event ID 1002.

Comment: 1001/1002 are the events for when an app crashes, but not for when a dmp file gets created

Comment: @Kamil Windows Error Reporting. I dont have a link on me at the moment, I looked in my own event log.